# Android phonegap code to get the directory path?

Tags: android, cordova

```
function onDeviceReady(){
getFileSystem();} 

function getFileSystem(){
window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0,
    function(fileSystem){ 
        root = fileSystem.root;
        listDir(root);
}, function(evt){ 
        console.log("File System Error: "+evt.target.error.code);
    }
);
}
```

Above code which gives the root directory, that is sdcard. My requirement is that i need to get the path of the folder named 'mydata' which is in sdcard using android phonegap code. Or plz help me get the the path of default folders like DCIM, Pictures etc in sdcard.

I alot tried but i didn't got result what i need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the [document](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.2.0/cordova_file_file.md.html#GetDirectory) given by Phonegap:

**getDirectory**

Creates or looks up an existing directory. It is an error to attempt to:

- create a directory whose immediate parent does not yet exist.

**Parameters:**

**path** - The path to the directory to be looked up or created. Either an absolute path, or a relative path from this DirectoryEntry. (DOMString)
**options** - Options to specify whether the directory is created if it doesn't exist. (Flags)
**successCallback** - A callback that is invoked with a DirectoryEntry object. (Function)
**errorCallback** - A callback that is called if an error occurs creating or looking up the directory. Invoked with a FileError object. (Function)

**Quick Example**

```
function success(parent) {
    console.log("Parent Name: " + parent.name);
}

function fail(error) {
    alert("Unable to create new directory: " + error.code);
}

// Retrieve an existing directory, or create it if it does not already exist
entry.getDirectory("existingDirectoryPath", {create: true, exclusive: false}, success, fail);
```